# What are "large vectors" in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

Using RStudio:

```
a <- rep(1, 1e4)
b <- rep(1, 1e5)
```

In the environment pane, `a` and `b` are displayed differently:

[image]

What's the meaning of `Large numeric`? I used to think that it meant that `b` was handled in a special way by R, but using `str` I can't see anything special. I also read about [long vectors](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-ints.html#Long-vectors), but it seems it's only about vectors with length >= 2^31.

Is it a purely informative comment added by RStudio to notify the user that an object's memory size is bigger than an arbitrary limit?

Comment: Right; it's just an arbitrary limit / description and isn't related to the underlying structure of the object. You're also correct that this is a separate thing from R's own so-called 'long vectors'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a qualifier for objects larger than a half MB. [See line 460 here](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/c4c3639f023f2d4cbf5b05ac75e116d18f897719/src/cpp/session/modules/SessionEnvironment.R).

> ```
>   # for large objects (> half MB), don't try to get the value, just show
>   # the size. Some functions (e.g. str()) can cause the object to be
>   # copied, which is slow for large objects.
>   if (size > 524288)
>   {
>      len_desc <- if (len > 1) 
>                paste(len, " elements, ", sep="")
>             else 
>                ""
>      # data frames are likely to be large, but a summary is still helpful
>      if (is.data.frame(obj))
>      {
>         val <- "NO_VALUE"
>         desc <- .rs.valueDescription(obj)
>      }
>      else
>      {
>         val <- paste("Large ", class, " (", len_desc, 
>                      capture.output(print(size, units="auto")), ")", sep="")
>      }
>      contents_deferred <- TRUE
>   }
> ```

As per the comment, this prevents a later `str()` call from copying the object, improving performance for large objects.

The `paste("Large", ...)` call creates the modified description.

On my computer, this can be demonstrated here:

```
small <- 1:131050
large <- 1:132000

object.size(small)
# 524240 bytes
object.size(large)
# 528040 bytes
```

Comment: Thanks! Out of curiosity: how did you manage to find this in the huge RStudio repo? (I had a look before asking the question, but my only keyword was "large", which is not very helpful...)

Comment: @Scarabee I used the gitbhub search functionality - keyword "large environment" or "large numeric environment", and looked for a module that looked like it controlled the Environment window. Within the candidates I looked manually for "large" and found the above.